# Select ranges containing values

Tags: postgresql, range

I have a table which contains ranges:

```
+----+------+----+
| id | from | to |
+----+------+----+
|  1 |    1 | 10 |
|  2 |   11 | 20 |
|  3 |   21 | 30 |
+----+------+----+
```

I have a list of values: `(5, 7, 16)`

I would like to select all of the ranges which contain one of these values:

```
+-------+----------+
| value | range_id |
+-------+----------+
|     5 |        1 |
|     7 |        1 |
|    16 |        2 |
+-------+----------+
```

Or maybe just the contained range ids, I can also work with that: `(1, 2)`

I've looked into `numrange` and using [range operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html), but I have not found 
 an operator for testing multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use `<@` (element is contained by) operator:

```
WITH sample (id, "from", "to") AS (
    VALUES 
        (1, 1, 10),
        (2, 11, 20),
        (3, 21, 30)
)
SELECT 
    ranges.val,
    sample.id 
FROM 
    sample
    --You can inject you array of values in a call of unnest function to simplify your query
    JOIN UNNEST(ARRAY[5, 7, 16]) AS ranges(val) ON (ranges.val <@ int4range(sample."from", sample."to"));
```

Also avoid using reserved words like "from" and "to". Escaping this is very tedious.

Answer (score 0):

A range operator is indeed the way to go:

```
select t.value, r.id
from ranges r
  join (values (5),(7),(16) ) as t(value)
    on t.value <@ int4range(r."from", r."to");
```

By creating a "virtual table" using the `values()` [row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-values.html), it's possible to also display the matching value.

If you expect some values to *not* match, and you want that information use an outer join:

```
select t.value, r.id
from ( values (5),(7),(16),(42) ) as t(value) 
  left join ranges r on t.value <@ int4range(r.from, r.to);
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/BIKSH85499